# DATABASE - Privilege for a user to be able to drop tables in a database but not the database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, shell, mariadb

I am in the process of setting up a database where a user has the right to access a database. The problem is that I want this user to have the privileges to create and drop tables, but he should not have the ability to create and drop databases, even the databases assigned to him.

I read in the documentations of MariaDB and MySQL that the DROP privilege applies to databases, tables and views :

- https://mariadb.com/kb/en/grant/#comments
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_drop

For my part, I tried this commands :

- After create my database, I give to MY_USER, all privileges, and this is where I saw that the user could do whatever he wants on the database (even delete it).
  Command :

```sql
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON "MY_DATABASE".* TO "MY_USER"@"localhost"; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

- After that, I revoke privileges and I tried to give some privileges to MY_USER but not DROP privilege, it's work, the user can't drop the database but after creating a table in the database, he can't drop it.
  Command:

```sql
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON "MY_DATABASE".* FROM "MY_USER"@"localhost"; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, [...] ON `MY_DATABASE`.* TO `MY_USER`@`localhost`; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

So I would like to know if it is possible to set up a rule or if a database management web application, type Adminer or PHPMyAdmin allow my user to create and delete the tables contained in a database but not the database itself.

Thank you in advance and have a good day !

Comment: Is it really meaningful that a user can't drop a database if they're capable of dropping all tables within it? A database with zero tables contains zero useful data.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I totally agree, if a user has the option to drop all tables from a database they might as well drop the database. 

Now the problem is that I want this user to be able to create the database again if and only if the original database has been drop.
In other words, the user has the possibility to create a single database only if its name is the same as the original one and the original one has been drop.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it appears as though this is an outstanding bug in MariaDB that has been parked for quite awhile: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-13398

The main issue brought up in the bug ticket is ensuring backwards compatibility with this issue would be difficult for those that are relying on the DROP database.* privilege to also be able to drop the schema.